# Previous Versions/Builds of Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, build, download, version

We write Web Applications. I have a client who is reporting an issue that seems that it may be related to a specific version of IE6. IE6.0.2900.2180 to be precise.

Does anyone know where I can download specific historical builds of IE in order to test problems such as this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at expression web [superpreview](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd565874.aspx), there maybe an IE image somewhere you could load into that.